# Как переходить на новое Activity из кнопки в RecyclerView, и передовать положение itema

Tags: recyclerview, android-on-click

Меня интересует вопрос, как сделать так чтобы кнопка понимала к какому Itemy она относится, и переходила на Activity при этом отправляя запрос на сервер чтобы тут загрузил на это Activity данные

package com.maikmarelostydios.a240417gid;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class HotelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter{

```
private List<Hotel> list;

public HotelAdapter(List<Hotel> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public UserViewHotel onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new UserViewHotel(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_hotel , parent, false));
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHotel holder, final int position) {
  Hotel hotel = list.get(position);

    holder.TvName.setText(hotel.name);
    holder.TvStar.setText("star:"+hotel.star + "");



    holder.btPodrob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),HotelViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(HotelViewActivity.EXTRA_POS, position);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}




@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}




class UserViewHotel extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView TvName, TvStar;
    Button btPodrob;



    public UserViewHotel(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        TvName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TvName);
        TvStar = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TvStar);
        btPodrob = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btPodrob);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалите код:

```
holder.btPodrob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),HotelViewActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(HotelViewActivity.EXTRA_POS, position);
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Loading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

А затем во `ViewHolder` пропишите `intent` с `putExtra`

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(UserViewHotel holder, final int position) {
  Hotel hotel = list.get(position);

holder.TvName.setText(hotel.name);
holder.TvStar.setText("star:"+hotel.star + "");

 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), HotelViewActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(HotelViewActivity.EXTRA_POS, position);
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Затем в `activity` в которую происходит `intent` добавьте статическую переменную

```
static final String EXTRA_POS = "my_item_position";
```

А в метод `onCreate`

```
int my_item_position = (Int) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_POS);
```

И если вы будете получать данные с БД то сделайте следующее:

```
try {
        SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new YourSQLiteOpenHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                "TABLE", new String[]{"ITEMS"},
                "_id = ?",
                new String[]{Integer.toString(my_item_position )},
                null, null, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            ITEMS = cursor.getString(0);

        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Toast.makeText(HeadsActivity.this, "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

По строке

```
new String[]{Integer.toString(my_item_position )} БД будет знать какие данные передавать в `activity` в соответствии с нажатым пунктом.
```

Comment: Я сделал все как вы описали, но не понял что изменилось ...

Comment: Вы привели фрагмент кода из вашего `RecyclerViewAdapter`а, его родитель это ваше `activity` в котором вы получили доступ, и затем которое обращается к этому адаптеру и выдает список в `RecyclerView`. Вам нужно, чтобы по нажатию на `item`ы в `RecyclerView` происходил `intent` и `activity` которая будет открываться должна будет понимать что нажат например, 5 пункт из списка, и будет загружать в установленные в себе `view` элементы данные в соответствии с кликнутым пунктом, так?

Comment: Да, все верно .

Comment: Тогда покажите весь код вашего адаптера, если это возможно.

Comment: Не могу поместить весь текст в комментарий, как мне поделится им с вами ?

Comment: Отредактируйте ваше сообщение где фрагмент кода, и туда добавьте весь код.

Comment: Добавил, можете посмотреть

Comment: Отредактировал свое сообщение

Comment: Я немного не разобрался как отличить какая кнопка была нажата, уже для загрузки в View,

Comment: Я использую базу данный от Firedase там система работы такая же ?

Comment: В этом уже не смогу вам ответ дать.

Comment: Спасибо, вы уже и так много помогли.

Comment: Помню когда глупый совсем был делал для каждого итема активность, эх

Comment: Я сам свои недавние приложения смотрю и в шоке. Более 30 активити))

Comment: У вас в статусе опечатка - не `гараздо`, а `гораздо` :)

Comment: У меня в последнее время все на одной происходит. Как - ума не приложу

Comment: @Flippy у меня данные динамичные , я не могу позволить себя заранее создать Activity, но благо мне помогли и я смог во всем этом разобраться